# How to tell if two sprites are actually colliding and not just "touching" in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Trying to make a basic platformer and having trouble understanding how to detect collisions and deal with the Sprite superclass. I was learning from a more turn-based ish game, and they were using something similar to:

```
world_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.world, False)
```

to detect collisions and then moving the self sprite's rect to match the bottom/top/left/right of the self.world object to keep you separate. The problem I'm running into is that if you are "touching" another sprite (ie, standing on a platform), this qualifies as colliding despite not actually overlapping. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this so that I'm only detecting when the player sprite is overlapping, not just next to. I was thinking about just creating a separate collisionrect that is one pixel smaller on each side, but all of sprite.Sprite's functionality is based on using the object's self.rect, I don't get how I would use separate rects for spritecollide and draw, etc. so I'm not sure if I'm on the right train of thought there.

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm a beginner in pygame and I didn't really understand the question but it looks to me that you want to reduce the hitbox:

```
self.rect.inflate(negative value x,nagative value y)
```